# BLE scan timeout in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, timeout, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am having an app in which I start and perform a BLE scan. Every thing is fine. I just want to know that is there a feature for creating a timeout for the scanning process. 
So that if BLE scan cannot find any device for a certain period of time, I can show an alert or popup to the user.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You can set a NSTimer, a performSelector afterDelay, and check the list of found CBPeripheral.

Comment: Is there no way I can do it through Core Bluetooth APIs?

Comment: No, you simply have to stop scanning when you decide it has been long enough.

Comment: Thanks paul and larme

Answer (score 4):

swift 3

```
var timer: Timer!
var countTime: Int = 0
var bleCentralManager: CBCentralManager!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateScanningStatus), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateScanningStatus(){

    if self.count >= 60{

        bleCentralManager.stopScan()

        timer.invalidate()

        timer = nil
    } else {
        count += 1
    }
}
```

after 1 min BLE scanning is stop.